# creating a side-smartcontract for Solana Token

Tags: blockchain, solana, solana-web3js

I have created a token on the Solana Blockchain but i want to devise a part of it to a different issuer that will start a different ICO than mine.
Who can shed some light into this ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an opinion / design question, but if you want to have two issuers for the same token, you have a few options:

- mint a bunch of tokens for the second issuer, and have them burn whatever isn't sold
- create a separate on-chain program to handle minting, and accepts a signature from either you or the second issuer
- each create your own token, then have them redeemable for the ICO token through a program

Comment: awesome answer it worked

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by removing the old repo and cloned it again. This solves the issue for the merge. Also please be careful of any addon on your code editor that could change the position of the code that you have in the file. If necessary you can contact me to debug it.